# Как вывести информацию о всех ошибках из блока catch

Tags: c++, исключения

Как получить информацию о всех переменных которые являются неправильными, а не только первой -1

```
#include "pch.h"
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
try
{
    for (int i = 10; i >= -3; --i)
    {
        if (i < 0) throw i;

        cout << "i= " << i << ",sqrt= " << sqrt(i) << endl;
    }
}
catch (int i)
{

        cout << i << endl;

}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: имейте привычку  в С++ не называть обьекты переменными. Если возникает исключительная ситуация, то обрабатывается это исключение. После происходит  раскрутка стека,  вызывется  terminate(), программа заканчивает свою работу так что незачем обработать другие исключения.

Comment: а существует способ для просмотра всех однотипных исключений?

Comment: да catch (std::exception& exc) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имейте привычку в С++ не называть обьекты переменными. Если возникает исключительная ситуация, то обрабатывается это исключение. После происходит раскрутка стека, вызывется terminate(), программа заканчивает свою работу так что незачем обработать другие исключения. Если все же хотите обработать, то нужно, чтобы этот обработчик был в цикле. Вы наверное хотели выполнить следующее:

```
for (int i = 10; i >= -3; --i)
{
    try {
        if (i < 0) throw i;
        cout << "i= " << i << ",sqrt= " << sqrt(i) << endl;
    }
    catch (int i)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Евгений При всей работоспособности кода это уже извращение, и если это требует преподаватель - то он не понимает самой сути исключений С++. Здесь `i<0` никак не исключительная, а просто обычная рабочая ситуация.

Answer (score 1):

Исключения на то и исключения, что нормальная работа прерывается. А вывести все значения - это значит, что работа у вас нормальная.

Вариант - выводите сразу без исключений

```
for (int i = 10; i >= -3; --i)
{
    if (i < 0) cout << "Неверное " << i << endl;
    else
        cout << "i= " << i << ",sqrt= " << sqrt(i) << endl;
}
```

Второй - накапливайте неверные значения, скажем, в векторе, а потом, по окончании цикла, выводите их все.

Comment: В порядке бреда :) - использовать знания о конкретном цикле, и в `catch` вывести все значения от текущего `i` до -3 :)

Comment: первый способ в виде условия я реализовал, просто интересно преподователь может прикапаться и заставить выводить ошибки при помощи catch или это некомпитентное задание

Comment: Я считаю, что некомпетентное. Я сейчас не найду ту книжку, но у кого-то из великих было - что исключения - только для исключительных ситуаций и ни в коем случае не для обработки ситуаций, которые могут быть предусмотрены программистом. Если программист знает, что может произойти, и знает, как это обработать, не выходя из функции - он не должен прибегать с исключениям. Типа для выхода из глубоко вложенного цикла или еще чего такого. У вас отрицательные значения не ошибка и не исключение, тем более если их может быть много. Это просто очень плохое проектирование.

Comment: слышали звон, да не знаем где он...  Эти задания являются лишь тренировкой, а не частью серьезной программы. Не важно кто что сказал, важно самому понять минусы неуместных генераций исключений, но до этого еще нужно понять как их вообше генерировать и как обработать....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Учиться надо правильно сразу. Нельзя сначала учиться прыгать с вышки, а потом наливать в бассейн воду :)